# How to Mock repository calls ATG

Tags: mockito, atg

Can we use Mockito to write tests for methods which implements repository calls? For example below method is using Named query to get eBooks from a Book Repository -

```
public RepositoryItem[] getEBooks(DynamoHttpServletRequest request) {
    RepositoryItem[] results = null;
    Repository rep = (Repository) request.resolveName("/atg/products/BookRepository");
    try {
        RepositoryItemDescriptor desc = rep.getItemDescriptor("Book");
        RepositoryView view = desc.getRepositoryView();
        if (view instanceof NamedQueryView) {
            NamedQueryView nameView = (NamedQueryView) view;
            ParameterSupportView pSupportView = (ParameterSupportView) view;
            String queryName = "GetBooks";
            Query namedQuery = nameView.getNamedQuery(queryName);
            Object[] params = { "ebook" }; //book type
            results = pSupportView.executeQuery(namedQuery, params);
        }
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        logError(e.getMessage());
    }
    return results;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. The question is though are you testing YOUR code or ATG in this instance?

Assuming your method above is contained in a class called `GetBooks` your test could look something like this:

```
@InjectMocks  private GetBooks testObj;

@Mock private DynamoHttpServletRequest requestMock;
@Mock private Repository bookRepositoryMock;
@Mock private RepositoryItemDescriptor bookRepositoryItemDescriptorMock;
@Mock private GSAView bookRepositoryViewMock; //The only oddity here but GSAView is the common denominator for NamedQueryView and ParameterSupportView 
@Mock private Query namedQueryMock; 

@Mock private RepositoryItem resultRepositoryItem1, resultRepositoryItem2;


@BeforeMethod(groups = { "unit" })
public void setup() throws Exception {
    testObj = new GetBooks();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 

    Mockito.when(requestMock.resolveName("/atg/products/BookRepository")).thenReturn(bookRepositoryMock);
    Mockito.when(bookRepositoryMock.getItemDescriptor("Book")).thenReturn(bookRepositoryItemDescriptorMock);
    Mockito.when(bookRepositoryItemDescriptorMock.getRepositoryView()).thenReturn(bookRepositoryViewMock);
    Mockito.when(bookRepositoryViewMock.getNamedQuery("GetBooks")).thenReturn(namedQueryMock);

    List<RepositoryItem> resultArrayList = new ArrayList<RepositoryItem>();
    resultArrayList.add(resultRepositoryItem1);
    resultArrayList.add(resultRepositoryItem2);

    Object[] params = { "ebook" }; //It may be simpler to test if this was a constant

    Mockito.when(bookRepositoryViewMock.executeQuery(namedQueryMock, params)).thenReturn(resultArrayList.toArray(new RepositoryItem[resultArrayList.size()]));

}

@Test(groups = { "unit" })
public void testGetEBooks()throws Exception{ 

    RepositoryItem[] result = testObj.getEBooks(requestMock);
    Assert.assertTrue(result.length == 2); //What do you want to test?
}
```

This gives a `greenbar` when executed via `TestNG`. But what are you really testing here?

On a separate note. You should really use (`protected`) constants more since you'll then be able to use them in the package scope of your `Mockito` tests.

Comment: Thanks. Well the purpose is to test the method not ATG. Typically, a method having repository calls take some parameter, execute a query using that parameter and return the result. The question is, can't we avoid writing test for such method assuming ATG would be playing it's role correctly. OR, we should write a minimal approach as you have explained above.

Comment: @Saurabh On a project I've worked on we've written hundreds of tests for droplets and formhandlers and in most cases this involved getting data out of a repository. Our tests were mostly focused on what we do with the data from the repository and not (as is the case above) how we get the data. Unfortunately you sometimes have to Mock how you get the data in order to test the use of the data so it all depends. The above approach has worked quite well for me and I'm applying it on my current project as well.

Comment: Thanks. These notes will guide me while writing tests in my project. :)

Comment: As you said form handlers, what we generally test? Because, the purpose of a form handler is to take form inputs, call some service to perform logic and finally redirect to either error page (if there is any error) or a success page. And in ATG we generally call checkFormRedirect(getSuccessUrl(), getErrorUrl(), request, response);

Comment: It all depends. Do you validate your form inputs? Do you validate that in a separate class or in the FormHandler? Do you test the validation? If your validation fails, how do you know that you go to the successUrl? How many conditions do you have in your handle method? How many of these do you test? Just because you end up on a success or error Url doesn't mean that you are supposed to? In a 'clean' implementation you won't have much logic in your FormHandlers but even in the Out-of-the-Box FormHandlers you have multiple success paths so how do you know your ultimate page is correct? Test it.

Comment: Agreed. Yes, we do write validation code inside the form handlers. And we have to test these code along with other chunks of code. The idea is to break the code in units and write the test.