# ATG Repository mockObject.method return null

Tags: java, junit, mockito, atg

I have a code, when I run this, It return null, condition inside when() return null

```
    try{
    obj.setRepository(repositoryMock);
        Mockito.when(repositoryMock.getView("promotion")).thenReturn(promotionViewMock);
}catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: There is quite a comprehensive example of how to Mock Repository calls available on SO already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987180/how-to-mock-repository-calls-atg. I suspect you are missing the setup of your `repositoryMock`.

Comment: Have you tried this syntax? doReturn(promotionViewMock).when(repositoryMock).getView("promotion");

Comment: @MattSidesinger I tried with 'Mockito.doReturn(promotionViewMock).when(repositoryMock).getView("promotion");' but it is giving null.

Comment: Could we get the full stack trace, perhaps, or is either promotionViewMock or repositoryMock null?